# Oracle SQL privelege authorization on multiple attributes and tables with one statement

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

Is it possible to grant different privileges on different tables or attributes within the one statement?

For example I want to combine:

```
GRANT SELECT ON tbl TO user;
```

and

```
GRANT UPDATE OF attr ON tbl TO user;
```

Furthermore, could I combine granting privilege on a different relation:

```
GRANT INSERT ON tbl2;
```

All in the one statement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can combine multiple object privileges in one `GRANT`, but only for the same object.  For example:

```
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE(column1, column2), INSERT on TBL to user;
```

But, as you can see in the [manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9013.htm)'s syntax diagram, each `GRANT` can only operate on one object at a time.

[image]

However, you can run multiple `GRANT`s as a single statement if you use the `CREATE SCHEMA` syntax.

```
CREATE SCHEMA AUTHORIZATION owner_user
GRANT SELECT ON TBL TO user
GRANT SELECT ON TBL2 TO user;
```

If you're looking to simplify your code, this won't help.  But if you have some technical requirement to use a single statement, it may work.  For example, I've often found that combining DDL statements can significantly reduce the time it takes to run install scripts, especially over a slow network.