# Grant SELECT on multiple tables oracle

Tags: select, oracle11g, sql-grant

I have 3 tables table1,table2,table3.
I want to grant(select for example) these tables to a user, user1.

I know that I can grant with:

```
grant select on table1 to user1;
grant select on table2 to user1;
grant select on table3 to user1;
```

Can I grant the 3 tables to user1 using only 1 query?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle SQL privelege authorization on multiple attributes and tables with one statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13106087/oracle-sql-privelege-authorization-on-multiple-attributes-and-tables-with-one-st)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No. As the [documentation shows](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9013.htm#SQLRF01603), you can only grant access to one object at a time.

---

Oracle Database 23c has extended `grant` to allow you to give [one user access to all tables in another schema](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/dbseg/configuring-privilege-and-role-authorization.html#GUID-EEE53C39-D610-4792-82EA-6F49B880B036):

```
grant select any table
  on schema table_owner
  to query_user;
```

Answer (score 9):

You can do it with dynamic query, just run the following script in pl-sql or sqlplus:

```
select 'grant select on user_name_owner.'||table_name|| 'to user_name1 ;' from dba_tables t where t.owner='user_name_owner'
```

and then execute result.

Comment: are you supposed to copy / paste the result to execute it?

Comment: @justincress, with this answer you will get a series of sentences that will save you time. I would call it a workaround.

Comment: You need a space just before and after the text  ||table_name||

Answer (score 5):

my suggestion is...create role in oracle using

```
create role <role_name>;
```

then assign privileges to  that role using

```
grant select on <table_name> to <role_name>;
```

then assign that group of privileges via that role to any user by using

```
grant  <role_name> to <user_name>...;
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on my Oracle database:

```
SELECT   'GRANT SELECT, insert, update, delete ON mySchema.' || TABLE_NAME || ' to myUser;'
FROM     user_tables
where table_name like 'myTblPrefix%'
```

Then, copy the results, paste them into your editor, then run them like a script.

You could also write a script and use "Execute Immediate" to run the generated SQL if you don't want the extra copy/paste steps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to grant to both tables and views try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    || OWNER
    || '.'
    || TABLE_NAME
    || ' to db_user;'
FROM
    ALL_TAB_COLS 
WHERE
    TABLE_NAME LIKE 'TABLE_NAME_%';
```

For just views try:

```
SELECT
    'grant select on '
    || OWNER
    || '.'
    || VIEW_NAME
    || ' to REPORT_DW;'
FROM
    ALL_VIEWS
WHERE
    VIEW_NAME LIKE 'VIEW_NAME_%';
```

Copy results and execute.