# Granting execute on multiple functions

Tags: oracle

How do I grant the execute privilege on multiple objects in Oracle? The following command (assuming that I am `USER1`) selects the objects I want to give access to:

```
select object_name from all_objects
where owner = 'USER1'
and REGEXP_LIKE(object_name, '^TEST')
```

..but trying to use it in a `grant` statement doesn't work:

```
grant execute on
  (select object_name from all_objects
   where owner = 'USER1' and
   REGEXP_LIKE(object_name, '^TEST')) 
to USER2;
```

-- the error is:

```
SQL Error: ORA-00903: invalid table name
00903. 00000 -  "invalid table name"
```

[Another answer has suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19924594/889604) that a dynamic query can be used in a pl/sql script, but I'm looking for a plain SQL command, like is seemingly possible with [SQLServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020704/sql-grant-execute-on-multiple-objects).

Is there a way without writing a procedure to do it?

Comment: Also relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13106337/458741

Comment: Thanks for the link :) although I'm still a bit confused - am I right in thinking it's not possible at all to grant privileges on multiple objects in 1 statement *without* using pl/sql?

Comment: That's correct @Chris, yes.

Comment: Ah, ok - thanks; confusion cleared!